# how to avoid page to scroll upon clicking on asp.net radio button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an asp.net radio button and on clicking that I call a method, when user clicks on that radio button, the system scrolls up to the top of page, In order to avoid it I have used different solutions mentioned by other people like the one below, but the problem is this that the page scrolls to the top of page and then returns to its original location. Is there any solution to prevent scrolling ?

This is the source code:

```
<asp:TableCell>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbSubscription" runat="server"  OnCheckedChanged="HighlightSubscription" AutoPostBack="true"/>
</asp:TableCell>

<%--Script to avoids Page Scroll--%>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfPosition" Value="" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var f = $("#<%=hfPosition.ClientID%>");
        window.onload = function () {
            var position = parseInt(f.val());
            if (!isNaN(position)) {
                $(window).scrollTop(position);
            }
        };
        window.onscroll = function () {
            var position = $(window).scrollTop();
            f.val(position);
        };
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You may just want to set [`MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `True` and avoid reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: Thanks Cory for your comment, Unfortunately using this also causes the page to scroll to top and the re-scroll to current position.

Comment: How about using an UpdatePanel? There would be no scrolling to the top because the postback would be called via ajax.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use UpdatePanel in this page

Comment: Are you asking how to *prevent* rescrolling to the current position? The JavaScript is causing it to rescroll, not preventing it as the comment in the code states. Remove the JavaScript and it won't rescroll.

Comment: I want the page to stay at the current location without scrolling to top and returning to current location that causes the flicker

Comment: @albertsh: A postback is an entire re-rendering and loading of the page. There's no way to avoid the visible flicker of the re-scroll except by disabling `AutoPostBack`, using AJAX to submit the form instead, and some DOM manipulation to update anything that needs to change. This is just how browsers work, regardless of technology.